# Loading only just table rows from external javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, external

I am trying to have a table where the headers are there when page loads, but when a user presses a button, I would like to load the rest of the table (the trs and tds of the table) into the myTableInsertRows div, which is coming from an external js file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div id="container">
    <button onclick="getScript('Insert.js')"> Insert TR/TDs </button> 
    <div id="Table">
      <table id='TableResult1'>
        <th>Color</th>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Letter</th>
        <div id="myTableInsertRows"></div> 
       </table>
    </div> 
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    getScript=(url)=>{
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
      script.setAttribute('src', url);
      if(document.body == null){
         document.head.appendChild(script);
      }else{
         document.body.appendChild(script);
      }
    }
  </script>
```

External JS file

```
var Insert= ' \
<tr><td>Red</td><td>One</td><td>AAAA</td></tr> '
document.getElementById('myTableInsertRows').innerHTML =Insert;
```

Comment: Lots to comment on here in terms of writing proper JS (don't use `var`, don't use `on...` attributes on the HTML side, don't inline your script source, but if you do, put it inside the head or body, not outside. Don't use `==`, follow JS naming conventions, etc) but for the main problem: what makes you think it's not working? Are you seeing errors in your dev console?

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans when I click the button, the Red One AAAA is showing above the table headers and is not part of the table

Comment: And then you look at your code again: what does it do? It tries to inject table content into an element with id `myTableInsertRows`: what is that element? Can table content go in there? Is your HTML valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table id='TableResult1'>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Color</th>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Letter</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTableInsertRows"></tbody> 
</table>
```

You must follow the table structure in which `<tr>` should be in `<tbody>` or `<thead>` tag. I hope this will fix your issue.